# Disambiguating calls to functions taking std::functions

Tags: c++, function, lambda, c++11, ambiguity

The code below doesn't compile on gcc 4.5 because the call to foo is ambiguous.  What is the correct way to disambiguate it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void foo(std::function<void(int, int)> t)
{
    t(1, 2);
}

void foo(std::function<void(int)> t)
{
    t(2);
}

int main()
{
    foo([](int a, int b){ cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to explicitly create a `std::function` object of the correct type then pass that object to the function:

```
std::function<void(int, int)> func = 
    [](int a, int b) { cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl; }
foo(func);
```

or inline:

```
foo(
    std::function<void(int, int)>(
        [](int a, int b) { cout << "a: " << a << "b: " << b << endl; }
));
```

`std::function` has a constructor template that accepts anything:

```
template<class F> function(F);
```

Because of this, there's no way for the compiler to know during overload resolution which `foo` to select:  both `std::function<void(int)>` and `std::function<void(int, int)>` have a constructor that can take your lambda expression as an argument.

When you pass a `std::function` object directly, the `std::function` copy constructor is preferred during overload resolution, so it is selected instead of the constructor template.

---

**Answer for the future:**  If the capture list is guaranteed to be empty, you can also use ordinary function pointers.  In C++0x, a captureless lambda is implicitly convertible to a function pointer.  So, you can use something like

```
void foo(void (*t)(int, int)) { t(1, 2); }

void foo(void (*t)(int)) { t(1); }
```

and call `foo` directly with the captureless lambda (or a function pointer with matching type).

Note that this conversion is a very recent addition to the draft language standard (it was added in February of this year), so it is not likely to be widely supported yet.  Visual C++ 2010 doesn't support it yet; I don't know about the latest g++.

Comment: Isn't there some factory function for `std::function`, since type inference is allowed on template functions but not template classes?

Comment: @Ben:  I don't think a factory function is viable in this case.  Consider a function object that has two `operator()` overloads; how should the `std::function` type be selected?

Comment: @James: oops, forgot that even a non-capturing lambda is a function object.  Is there a factory function from function pointers, or have I totally lost it?

Comment: @Ben:  I was just scanning the C++0x draft spec and didn't see anything.

Comment: @James: Thanks for the reply; that certainly clears up why it is happening.  Since in my case the difference between overloads will always be the number of the parameter do you happen to know any way to use SFINAE to choose the correct function based on that.

Comment: @Ted:  Is the capture list always empty?  (i.e., is there always nothing inside of `[]`?)

Comment: @James: I currently can't think of a reason why I would need a non empty list for these functions.

Comment: @Ted:  I added a note about what you can do (someday).  I don't know whether gcc supports it, you'll have to test it.  I know for sure Visual C++ 2010 doesn't (not their fault; the standard was updated right before they released).

Comment: @Ted:  Out of curiosity, does the function pointer conversion work with g++ 4.5?

Answer (score 3):

I've recently been thinking about a similar problem and when looking around for any known solutions I came across this post and lack of solutions for resolving

An alternative solution is to abstract over the functor as a template argument and use decltype to resolve its type. So, the above example would become:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<class F>
auto foo(F t) -> decltype(t(1,2))
{
    t(1, 2);
}

template<class F>
auto foo(F t) -> decltype(t(2)) 
{
    t(2);
}

int main()
{
     foo([](int a, int b){ cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << endl;});
}
```

This works as expected with gcc 4.5.